# Should I pick the rhubarb that was attacked by the lawnmower?

Tags: rhubarb

Will a rhubarb stalk that got attacked by the lawnmower heal itself, or is it better to pick it, and feed it to the animals?

Comment: Make rhubarb crumble and eat it yourself? Isn't that why one plants rhubarb in the first place?

Comment: it is, but it's too small to really eat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how bad the damage is - it may form a callous, a woody area you won't want to eat anyway. Leave it, pick it, up to you, but if you're feeding anything with it, don't give the leaf, its toxic.

Comment: I picked it, since it wasn't coming back.